# Integral of holomorphic function takes a specific value

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find an holomorphic function $f : \mathbb{C}^* = \mathbb{C} \setminus 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that :
$$ \int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(e^{it})e^{int} dt = 2 \pi \vert n \vert !$$

I know that $\int_{\partial B(0,1)} f(z) dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{it})ie^{it} dt$ and also by the residue theorem I know the value of my integral will only be determined by the residue of my function at $0$. I have been thinking of $f(z) = \frac{\vert n \vert !}{z^n}$ but I'm not sure if it works for all $n$. (I know it does for $n = 1$.)

How does one proceed with such questions ? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a function does not exist.

Assume that $f$ has these properties. Then
$$
|n|! = \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} f(e^{it})e^{int} dt 
= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)}{z^{1-n}} \, dz = c_{-n}
$$
where $f(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_k z^k$ is the [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) of $f$ in $\mathbb{C} \setminus 0 $. So $f$ would necessarily be of the form
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k! \cdot z^k  + \sum_{k=1}^\infty k! \cdot z^{-k}\, .
$$
However, the radius of convergence of both these power series is zero, they do not converge for any $z \ne 0$.

Comment: I am quite confused as I do not think I should be able to express the coefficients of $f$ using the Cauchy Integral Formula since $f$ is not holomorphic at $z = 0$. (Also, this was asked in a past exam and I'm pretty sure there is a valid answer.)

Comment: @gazo: The same formula works for the coefficients of a Laurent series, you can find it in the Wikipedia article that I linked to.